# Node.js async setInterval game loop?

Tags: node.js

I have a multiplayer game lobby up where users can create private chatrooms and start private games. Each user has a health bar in the game that is suppose to slowly regenerate x points per second.

I suppose I would need to start server side game loop at the beginning of each game, which is something like that:

```
setInterval(update('gameID'),1000);
```

Where update('gameID') increment the health variables for all players in a particular game where 1000 ms = 1 second.

Question: Am I right to assume this is asynchronous? I might have 50 separate games going on, and 50 of these running. The main process is not going to be blocked right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is asynchronous. But doing this that way may kill your server.

I advice making these intervals passive, i.e. hold the start of the game in memory and make client ping for data. When client pings server checks current date and compares it to the stored one (and updates the stored one at the end of request). It can evaluate current health from that.

This solution should scale better.

Comment: Is it efficient enough to have a setInterval client side that calls a server-side "updateHealth()" function? Or should I tally all the possible actions (attack, heal etc) that modifies health points and make sure they call "updateHealth()" whenever they are used. Then, have client-side prediction for all the health values of all players (4 max) in the same active game.

Comment: I think that you should fire client-side `setInterval`, but not too often. You can make client calculate health and each 5 (or less) seconds you call server-side `synchronize` function which evaluates the true health (and other values) and sends it back to client, which updates the data. That's how I would do that, but perhaps the are other ways which are better.

Comment: The synchronize function would have to be called on actions like attacking, healing other players right? The server would need to update the health and then apply the changes.

I suppose while I am at it, I should change the regeneration interval to 5 seconds to help reduce server load. :p

Comment: Yes, exactly. Additionaly you can cache on the client-side the last update date and fire synchronize only when necessary. For example: `var t = setTimeout(synchronize, 5000);` and when an event appears (for example someone attacked you) you do `clearTimeout(t); t = setTimeout(synchronize, 5000);`, because you synchronize at the same time when event occurs. Inside `synchronize` function you set timeout again to the same variable `t`. You don't want to fire synchronization when there's action, this will reduce server load a bit. :)

Comment: Ah...VERY nice suggestion. Thanks for the very detailed discussion. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's asynchronous, but you don't need 50 timers in the case you describe.

1. You can use a single timer to regenerate players in active games. If you're also pushing health data this is going to be pretty inefficient.
2. You can do something like `player.attackedTime = (new Date).getTime()` and calculate regeneration on each attack like `player.health += x_points * ((new Date).getTime() - player.attackedTime) / 1000`, but you will have to do predictive regeneration on the client.

Comment: Doh. Yes, I can just run one setInterval(update(),1000) and let update() regenerate health of all players in all active games.

I suppose I would need a "updateHealth()" function that is called on all actions that has something to do with player health points? Not just attacking, but getting heal or damaged by traps etc too.

On the client side, just display a "dummy" predicted health value that gets synced with the authoritative server-side value when "updateHealth()" is called.

Comment: How you update health depends on how you've decided to store/abstract the state of the game on the server. You'll want to update clients on health changes that are not predictable (attacking, healing, etc.), but regen can be predicted to prevent frequent syncing, and you can even account for latency if your game requires that kind of timing precision.

Comment: Right now its just an array "var games = []" in app.js. When a game is created an entry is made: E.g. games['newGameName'] = { "One" : { health: 50 } }. So if player one gets healed for 20, I'll do a games['newGameName'].One.health += 20 etc.

Comment: There are some intricacies depending on the pace of your game (and how important the data is to the player), and this will affect how good a syncing strategy is. Also, make sure that if an attack depletes health, you kill off the player before something like a regen wrongly keeps him alive, e.g. queuing actions can cause this.

Comment: Ok thanks. Unfortunately I am only allowed to accept just 1 answer. Would love to accept yours as well.

Comment: No problem. To clarify, in something like a turn-based game, you can sync on most actions and be comfortable with server load as well as state accuracy, reserving "interval" syncs for clusters of frequent changes. If your game rewards players in any way (gold etc.), this data is much more important than, say, chat messages, so it's conceivable to use a combination of syncing strategies. Good luck on the game!

Comment: Thanks. Up voted the comment because of how generally helpful Loc Nguyen is. :)

Comment: Hope it's going well. Came across this excellent article you might find useful: http://buildnewgames.com/real-time-multiplayer/ .

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is certainly asynchronous. Most functions that take a callback are asynchronous. If you're ever in doubt, you can check the documentation or the source code.

Comment: I am pretty new to Node.js and server-side scripting in general, so am double checking my understanding with you guys. Glad to know I didn't mess up horribly on this one. Thanks for the speedy response. :)